# How to check if comments are paginated?

Tags: php, comments, pagination

I'm trying to determine if there's more than one page of comments in single.php.

In archive.php I can do something like this to check if there's more than one page of posts:

```
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { 
    // There's more than one page of posts in this archive.
}
```

As far as I can tell, this doesn't work for comments. How can I check if comments are paginated in single.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just some additional info for the main comment query:*

Since you mentioned the global `$wp_query` object, we can see that it stores:

```
$wp_query->max_num_comment_pages = $comment_query->max_num_pages;
```

in the main comment query in the comments template.

There [exists a wrapper](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_pages_count) for this, namely:

```
get_comment_pages_count();
```

that's available after the main comment query.

If we need it before the main comment query runs, then we might check if
`get_comments_number( $post_id )` is greater than `get_option( 'comments_per_page' )`. But we should keep in mind that the `comments_per_page` parameter can be modified through e.g. the `comments_template_query_args` filter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `get_comment_pages_count()`!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `get_option( 'page_comments' )` will check if pagination is checked in options > discussion, then we compare comments per page (`get_query_var( 'comments_per_page' )`) to the current post's total comments found (count):

```
function wpse231229_is_paginate_comments( $post_id = 0 ) {
    return get_option( 'page_comments' )  && ( $pagi = (int) get_query_var( 'comments_per_page' ) ) && wp_count_comments( $post_id )->total_comments > $pagi;
}
```

Also, and to get the current page of comments (e.g `comment-page-1` in URL ..), use `(int) get_query_var( 'cpage' )`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I'm not sure that using the `total_comments` property is a good idea because that would take trashed and spammed comments in to account. These won't be displayed on the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `cpage` query variable:

```
if ( ! empty( get_query_var( 'cpage' ) ) ) {
    // There is more than one page of comments.
}
```